# How to generate an obfuscated jar file for a maven project

Tags: maven, proguard, java-7, obfuscation

I am working on a java application using maven architecture project in Eclipse IDE and  java 7

I need to generated an obfuscated a jar file which also must include all the dependencies obfuscated in it I've been checking some solutions around but I´ve been unable to get the desired result.

Some of the places that I've checked are this:

[Lin1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045474/obfuscate-dependencies-to-single-jar-with-proguard),[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275911/working-maven-obfuscate-example), [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774898/proguard-configuration-on-a-enterprise-java-application)

from the two first links I based most of my current implementation

this is my pom.xml file:

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>modeloconfigurador.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>CacheClienteModelC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>modeloconfigurador.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>Serializer</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency> -->
        <!--<groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId> -->
        <!--<artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
        <!--<version>2.0.4</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>CacheClienteModelC</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <!-- download source code in Eclipse, best practice -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Set a compiler level -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>

                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- comienza configuracion proguard -->


            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <proguardVersion>4.10</proguardVersion>
                    <options>

                        <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                        <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-small.jar</outjar>
                        <!-- <injar>CacheClienteModelC-jar-with-dependencies.jar</injar> -->
                        <!-- <outjar>CacheClienteModelC-small.jar</outjar> -->
                        <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                        <option>-keep public class main.Main { *; }</option>
                    </options>
                    <libs>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
                    </libs>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>4.10</version>
                        <!--<version>5.2.1</version> -->
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
            </plugin>


            <!-- termina configuracion proguard -->
        </plugins>


    </build>


</project>
```

the error  I'm getting is the following:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.pyx4me:proguard-maven-plugin:2.0.4:proguard (default) on project
>   CacheClienteModelC: Can't rename
>   E:\Users\B267481\Documents\ServidorDesarroCreditoAcertum\CacheClienteModelC\target\CacheClienteModelC.jar
>   -> [Help 1]

### EDIT

Just to make things more clear
When I build the project, two diferent jars are generated at the target folder (CacheClienteModelC-jar-with-dependecies.jar and CacheClienteModelC.jar), the file that I try to generate is  CacheClienteModelC-small.jar (obfuscated jar) which is never created.

How should I configure the plugin to obfuscate my project's file?

Comment: The line in the [ProGuardMojo](http://www.pyx4me.com/pyx4me-maven-plugins/j2me-maven-plugin/xref/com/pyx4me/maven/j2me/ProGuardMojo.html) that contains  _"Can't rename"_ uses `java.io.File.renameTo().` Have you checked all the possible reasons stated in its [Java API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File))?

Comment: From what understand if a file with the name I specified  in the `outjar` tag (${project.build.finalName}-small.jar) alredy exists the rename operation will fail but I checked and no such file exists.  By looking at my pom.xml, do you notice any error on it? This is my first trying to obfuscate a maven project and to be honest I'm quite lost on the correct implementation I should use with this plugin

Comment: I don't see any error in your POM at first sight. _"no such file exists"_? Shouldn't it? Created by the `maven-assembly-plugin` prior to the `proguard-maven-plugin`? You don't invoke your `mvn` build with the [`-T` option for parallel builds,](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3) do you? What if you put `assembly` and `proguard` in two separate build profiles and activate each of them in individual runs instead of performing both in the same run?

Comment: to be honest this is my first time trying to do this, I read this page https://goo.gl/IYBQ3x but the whole parallel builds  subject in maven it's new territory to me and i don´t have enough experience with it, I have worked mostly depending on the default settings from the maven eclipse puglin How do i define the build profiles with the plugin?

Comment: The reason why I asked for `-T` is: don't use it while troubleshooting! Because it may cause troubles on its own. For profiles see [Introduction to Build Profiles.](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an older version of the proguard plugin for Maven, you should use [this](http://wvengen.github.io/proguard-maven-plugin/) one, you can find it in the Maven Central repository.

Now as for your `pom.xml`, remove from the dependencies the `com.pyx4me` dependency, you won't need it there.

Now as for the plugin configuration try with something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
        <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
        <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-small.jar</outjar>
        <includeDependency>true</includeDependency>
        <options>
            <option>-keep public class your.package.Main { *; }</option>
        </options>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
        </libs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                <packageName>your.package</packageName>
            </manifest>
        </archive>

    </configuration>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

See how you specify the dependency for proguard in it? That should generate the obfuscated jar without problem. Try it out.

Comment: Can I use this in commercial product?

Comment: it does not work for me and do not create outut jar(obfuscated jar). what is the problem?